# Soft question: why are there non-smooth manifolds?

Tags: soft-question, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Topologists are often very good at explaining the geometric intuition behind certain results and programs of research.  For instance, the particular interest in 4 manifolds is often explained by saying "4 dimensions are enough to allow for certain constructions but not enough to allow one to undo those constructions" (or something like that).

What I'm wondering is, does there exist any sort of intuition for why certain topological manifolds do not admit smooth structures or triangulations.  This fact is extremely contrary to my naive intuition about manifolds, so I was hoping there might exist some counter-intuition behind it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58061/how-can-there-be-topological-4-manifolds-with-no-differentiable-structure

Comment: Yes, I suppose the last two answers do speak to this question. The language is slightly more technical than I was hoping for, but of course I don't have any reason to expect a less technical explanation to be possible.  So I won't be offended if this is closed :)

Comment: I'm more surprised that so many manifolds *do* have smooth structures! *A priori* topological manifolds could be pretty bizarrely behaved.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes maybe thats the right perspective. But specifically what sorts of "bizarre" behavior might make "non-smoothability" seem more intuitively plausible and why?  Whenever I picture a topological manifold I naively just allow  for certain regions to look "pointy" or "jagged", properties which certainly don't *intuitively* seem to prohibit a smooth structure.  But maybe it isn't fruitful to talk about such subtleties in such informal terms.

Comment: See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere (which is not so much about a manifold behaving bizarrely as a map between manifolds behaving bizarrely, but still). I'm also still mildly surprised that invariance of domain is true. I can easily imagine mathematicians in an alternate timeline starting out with the wrong definition of a topological manifold and invariance of domain being false with respect to that definition.

Comment: I prefer to think about these issues algebraically: when you choose a smooth structure on a topological manifold $M$ you pick out a nice subalgebra $C^{\infty}(M)$ of the algebra $C(M)$ of continuous functions on $M$. From the algebraic perspective there doesn't seem to be a good reason to expect this nice subalgebra to either exist or be unique in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for the link.  I definitely agree with you about invariance of domain as well as *uniqueness* of the smooth structure.

Comment: Your point about the algebraic perspective is helpful as well. However, there isn't much *at all* that I can intuit about the structure of manifolds from the module $C(M)$ but I'm quite sure that says more about me than it does about $C(M)$.